# Java - Make an excel workbook 'read-only' using jxl API

Tags: java, excel, jxl

How can I make my worksheet read-only? I'm using jxl to read and write excel files (.xls). I've been googling this the whole day.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the getSettings from your sheet and then setProtected(true) on those settings?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I actually found an answer a day ago. I used getSettings from my sheet and then setProtected(true) and then setLocked(true) the WritableCellFormat of each labels.